# How to know when React built-in component finished rendering?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm using a React rendered SVG from a file.

```
import React from 'react';
import {ReactComponent as SvgFrontPanel} from '../svg/panel.svg';

render() {
    return (<div className="panel">
    <h2>Panel</h2>
        <SvgFrontPanel/>
    </div>);
}
```

After svg is rendered I need to execute some init code for it. I can do it once via `window.onload` or `documentReady` or whatever usual way to check when the page is ready. But then, when this component gets unmounted/mounted, I cannot catch the moment.

I can use `componentDidMount` or put my code inside `render` of *this* component but it doesn't mean the svg inside `SvgFrontPanel` is rendered at the time.

So here is the question: **how can I understand when some uncontrolled component finished rendering?** Suppose I cannot modify svg file at all (actually I can but prefer not to).

Comment: You would need to pass a prop from the parent component and change it in the componentDidMount of SvgFrontPanel. But you dont want to modify anything from SvgFrontPanel?

Comment: SvgFrontPanel is not a real component, it is just a name of componentized svg from file. I cannot put any React there and don't want to put changes at all (svg is not created by me and any changes I will need to maintain by myself).

Comment: Look at componentDidUpdate() lifecycle event. It fires after component is rendered. shouldComponentUpdate() you can use to control trigger of update code. Just dont work with state inside this method without condition or you will create infinite loop.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg is nifty and gives you a callback with the SVG element when it's rendered and mounted.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, I'll probably stick to the library you pointed me on. It looks good. Thank you.